# Botões não mudam a cor

Tags: html, css

Os botões eram para ficar azuis de acordo com o `.rounded-button.blue`, mas estão pretos e apenas a borda funciona. O que tem de errado?

```css
.client-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.client-buttons button {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px;
  min-width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

button,
html input[type=button],
input[type=reset],
input[type=submit] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: buttontext;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: buttonface;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: buttonface;
  border-image: initial;
}

.rounded-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 48px;
  -moz-border-radius: 48px;
  border-radius: 48px;
  padding: 11px 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 47px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s, color .2s;
}

.rounded-button.plain {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s
}

.rounded-button {
  opacity: .85
}

.rounded-button:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.rounded-button.plain,
.rounded-button:not(.plain):hover {
  color: #2d74a6
}

.rounded-button.blue {
  color: #138cc8;
  border-color: #138cc8;
}

.rounded-button.blue:not([disabled]):not(.no-hover):hover,
.rounded-button.blue.plain {
  background-color: #138cc8;
  color: #fff;
}

.rounded-button:not(.white):not([disabled]):not(.no-hover):hover,
.rounded-button:not(.white).plain {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.rounded-button.blue {
  color: #138cc8;
  border-color: #138cc8;
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  float: left
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon.client-close-icon {
  background-image: url(../images/favicon-white.png?3);
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon.client-fullscreen-icon,
#hotel-container .client-buttons button .client-icon.client-fullscreen-icon-back {
  background-image: url(../images/web/fullscreen-icon.png);
  background-position: 0 -14px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 1px
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon.client-fullscreen-icon-back {
  background-position: 0 0
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon.hidden {
  display: none
}

.client-buttons button.client-close .client-close-expand {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transition: width .15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: width .15s ease-out 0s
}

.client-buttons button.client-close .client-close-expand span {
  padding: 1px 0 0 8px;
  display: inline-block
}

.client-buttons button.client-close:hover .client-close-expand {
  width: 50px
}

.client-buttons button.client-players {
  cursor: default
}

.client-buttons button.client-players .client-icon.client-players-icon {
  background-image: url(../images/web/players-icon.png);
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px
}

.client-buttons button.client-players .client-players-count {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 2px 0 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  display: inline-block
}

.client-frame {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="client-buttons">
  <button class="client-close rounded-button blue plain">
    <i class="client-icon client-close-icon"></i>
    <span class="client-close-expand"><span>Início</span></span>
    </button>
  <button class="client-fullscreen rounded-button blue plain">
    <i class="client-icon client-fullscreen-icon"></i>
    <i class="client-icon client-fullscreen-icon-back hidden"></i>
    </button>
  <button class="client-count rounded-button blue plain">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <b id="count">1,802</b> </button>
  <button class="client-radio rounded-button blue plain">
    <audio controls="controls" id="stream" autoplay="autoplay" preload="none" style="display:none" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;">
    
    <source id="source_mpeg" type="audio/mpeg" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;type=mp3">
    <source id="source_ogg" type="audio/ogg" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;type=ogg">
    <source id="source_aacplus" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;type=aacplus">
    <source id="source_wav" type="audio/wav" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;type=wav">
    </audio>
    <i class="fas fa-play" style="display: none;" title="Play/Pause"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-pause" style="" title="Play/Pause"></i>
    <span title="Locutor">
    <span id="streaming_info" style="display: none;">.Canabis</span>
    <i class="fas fa-microphone" style="margin-left: 8px;"></i> <span id="locutor">.Canabis</span>
    </span>
    <i style="margin-right: 4px;" class="fas fa-volume-down" title="Diminuir Volume"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-volume-up" title="Aumentar Volume"></i>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Na regra `.rounded-button:not(.white).plain` você define a cor de fundo `#333`. Os seus botões possuem a classe `.rounded-button`, não possuem a classe `.white` e possui a classe `.plain`, ou seja, satisfaz a regra, portanto devem ficar cinza.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss responde no lugar certo uai ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para entender o que está acontecendo com o seu elemento você pode (e deve) utilizar as ferramentas que o navegador lhe oferece. Basta você clicar com o *mouse* com o botão direito sobre o elemento e ir em Inspecionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na ferramenta será listados todos os estilos que estão sendo aplicados ao elemento e, principalmente, na ordem que estão sendo aplicados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que o último estilo aplicado foi

```
.rounded-button:not(.white):not([disabled]):not(.no-hover):hover,
.rounded-button:not(.white).plain {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

Onde você explicitamente fez o fundo ser cinza (`#333`). Se os botões deveriam ser azuis, ou esta regra está errada, ou você precisa rever a ordem que está aplicando os estilos no elemento.

Answer (score -3):

Isso ocorre porque você tem algum conflito de classes em um mesmo elemento, ou seja, alguma outra classe está aplicando a cor ao fundo depois, sobrescrevendo a cor azul que você deseja, como solução rápida, coloquei um '!important' nas cores da classe desejada. Lembrando que isso não é a maneira correta, o correto seria você procura a classe que está conflitando e verificar se realmente necessita fazer o uso de ambas, caso necessite utilizar as duas no mesmo elemento, por conta das propriedades empregadas em ambas, é aconselhável você dividir essas propriedades em mais classes, em ultimo caso, se isso não for possível, utilize o '!important' como eu fiz, que ele irá forçar o seu elemento utilizar a propriedade marcada da classe.

```css
.client-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.client-buttons button {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px;
  min-width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

button,
html input[type=button],
input[type=reset],
input[type=submit] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: buttontext;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: buttonface;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: buttonface;
  border-image: initial;
}

.rounded-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 48px;
  -moz-border-radius: 48px;
  border-radius: 48px;
  padding: 11px 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 47px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s, color .2s;
}

.rounded-button.plain {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s
}

.rounded-button {
  opacity: .85
}

.rounded-button:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.rounded-button.plain,
.rounded-button:not(.plain):hover {
  color: #2d74a6
}

.rounded-button.blue {
  color: #138cc8 !important;
  border-color: #138cc8 !important;
}

.rounded-button.blue:not([disabled]):not(.no-hover):hover,
.rounded-button.blue.plain {
  background-color: #138cc8 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.rounded-button:not(.white):not([disabled]):not(.no-hover):hover,
.rounded-button:not(.white).plain {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.rounded-button.blue {
  color: #138cc8 !important;
  border-color: #138cc8 !important;
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  float: left
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon.client-close-icon {
  background-image: url(../images/favicon-white.png?3);
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon.client-fullscreen-icon,
#hotel-container .client-buttons button .client-icon.client-fullscreen-icon-back {
  background-image: url(../images/web/fullscreen-icon.png);
  background-position: 0 -14px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 1px
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon.client-fullscreen-icon-back {
  background-position: 0 0
}

.client-buttons button .client-icon.hidden {
  display: none
}

.client-buttons button.client-close .client-close-expand {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transition: width .15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: width .15s ease-out 0s
}

.client-buttons button.client-close .client-close-expand span {
  padding: 1px 0 0 8px;
  display: inline-block
}

.client-buttons button.client-close:hover .client-close-expand {
  width: 50px
}

.client-buttons button.client-players {
  cursor: default
}

.client-buttons button.client-players .client-icon.client-players-icon {
  background-image: url(../images/web/players-icon.png);
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px
}

.client-buttons button.client-players .client-players-count {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 2px 0 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  display: inline-block
}

.client-frame {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="client-buttons">
  <button class="client-close rounded-button blue plain">
    <i class="client-icon client-close-icon"></i>
    <span class="client-close-expand"><span>Início</span></span>
    </button>
  <button class="client-fullscreen rounded-button blue plain">
    <i class="client-icon client-fullscreen-icon"></i>
    <i class="client-icon client-fullscreen-icon-back hidden"></i>
    </button>
  <button class="client-count rounded-button blue plain">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <b id="count">1,802</b> </button>
  <button class="client-radio rounded-button blue plain">
    <audio controls="controls" id="stream" autoplay="autoplay" preload="none" style="display:none" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;">
    
    <source id="source_mpeg" type="audio/mpeg" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;type=mp3">
    <source id="source_ogg" type="audio/ogg" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;type=ogg">
    <source id="source_aacplus" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;type=aacplus">
    <source id="source_wav" type="audio/wav" src="http://yoda.habblet.in:9999/;type=wav">
    </audio>
    <i class="fas fa-play" style="display: none;" title="Play/Pause"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-pause" style="" title="Play/Pause"></i>
    <span title="Locutor">
    <span id="streaming_info" style="display: none;">.Canabis</span>
    <i class="fas fa-microphone" style="margin-left: 8px;"></i> <span id="locutor">.Canabis</span>
    </span>
    <i style="margin-right: 4px;" class="fas fa-volume-down" title="Diminuir Volume"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-volume-up" title="Aumentar Volume"></i>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu votei -1 porque não vejo justificativas para utilizar `!important` neste caso. É uma "solução rápida", mas em tempo de desenvolvimento eu vejo como mais recomendado resolver o problema do que apenas contorná-lo. Sinceramente, eu acho que o CSS seria muito melhor se o `!important` não existisse.

Comment: !important é jogar a sujeira para debaixo do tapete

Comment: Ok, obrigado pelo comentário. Atualizei o post.